# Sound stops working in headphones every 2 minutes

Tags: audio, windows-10, headphones

I have a very weird problem. I have my headphones plugged into the jack in the front of my computer. The sound works fine when I first plug them in, then after a couple of minutes, the sound stops working.

Now when I unplug and plug the headphones back in, the sound works again. Then, after a couple minutes the sound stops working again. So I unplug and plug them back in.

This only happens with headphones and I've been able to replicate the issue using different headphones. It does not happen with my speakers.

I went into sound devices and the headphones are still set as the default when the sound stops working. It is very odd.

Why is this happening? If it was the jack then wouldn't the sound just not work at all? I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

> If it was the jack then wouldn't the sound just not work at all? I am using Windows 10.

That *seems* like it would make sense, yes. However the way to really rule out the jack would be to use USB headphones and see if the issue still persists.

If it does, then my best guess is there's a driver issue. If not then it's the 3.5mm jack or related to that.

To diagnose issues with the [driver](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/fix-sound-problems#v1h=tab01):

> Open **Start**, enter **Device Manager**, and select it from the list of results. Under Sound, video, and game controllers, select your sound card, open it, select the Driver tab, and select **Update Driver**. If Windows doesn't find a new driver, look for one on the device manufacturer's website and follow their instructions.

You can also lookup your Motherboard to get the sound driver from there, or if you're using a Laptop just lookup your laptop drivers.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with your internal dac, if it's works, then doesn't, try a usb dac, and if it's still doing it, turn in your computer to tech support.

Answer (score 0):

Late to answer, but someone might try to google the answer - In my case I had to change the frequency - Control panel >> Sounds >> Playback tab >> Choose your headphones (doubleclick) >> Advanced tab >> Default format > be sure it's not set to 96k hz.
Worked for me.